# Getting data from html spans into a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON of the span elements I managed to get the table but I'm stuck on at the data from the span elements here this is the output of "console.log(items);":

```
{"innerHTML":"<thead><tr><th class=\"text-center\"><i class=\"fas fa-edit\" id=\"\" style=\"font-size: 16px; opacity: 0.25\"></i></th><th class=\"text-center\"><i class=\"fas fa-print\" id=\"\" style=\"font-size: 16px; opacity: 0.25\"></i></th><th class=\"text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><a href=\"/customers?Take=50&amp;SortBy=0&amp;Desc=True&amp;FileID=VGVzdA\" class=\"text-neutral-500 hover:text-neutral-500 text-shadow dark:text-slate-400 dark:hover:text-slate-400 dark:text-shadow-none\">Code</a></th><th class=\"\"><a href=\"/customers?Take=50&amp;SortBy=1&amp;FileID=VGVzdA\" class=\"text-neutral-500 hover:text-neutral-500 text-shadow dark:text-slate-400 dark:hover:text-slate-400 dark:text-shadow-none\">Name</a></th><th class=\"\"><a href=\"/customers?Take=50&amp;SortBy=3&amp;FileID=VGVzdA\" class=\"text-neutral-500 hover:text-neutral-500 text-shadow dark:text-slate-400 dark:hover:text-slate-400 dark:text-shadow-none\">zone</a></th><th class=\"text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><a href=\"/customers?Take=50&amp;SortBy=4&amp;Desc=True&amp;FileID=VGVzdA\" class=\"text-neutral-500 hover:text-neutral-500 text-shadow dark:text-slate-400 dark:hover:text-slate-400 dark:text-shadow-none\">Invoices</a></th><th class=\"text-right w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><a href=\"/customers?Take=50&amp;SortBy=8&amp;Desc=True&amp;FileID=VGVzdA\" class=\"text-neutral-500 hover:text-neutral-500 text-shadow dark:text-slate-400 dark:hover:text-slate-400 dark:text-shadow-none\">Accounts receivable</a></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 1px\"><a href=\"/customer-form?Key=39cb2507-d07f-4357-987f-4451feee7b23&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\" class=\"bg-white border border-neutral-300 text-neutral-700 rounded py-1 px-4 hover:border-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-neutral-100 hover:shadow-inner dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700\" style=\"font-size: 11px\">Edit</a></td><td style=\"width: 1px\"><a href=\"/customer-view?Key=39cb2507-d07f-4357-987f-4451feee7b23&amp;Position=1&amp;MaxPosition=3&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\" class=\"bg-white border border-neutral-300 text-neutral-700 rounded py-1 px-4 hover:border-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-neutral-100 hover:shadow-inner dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700\" style=\"font-size: 11px\">View</a></td><td class=\"content text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span>D001</span></td><td class=\"content \"><span>customer 1</span></td><td class=\"content \"><span>A1</span></td><td class=\"content text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\"><a href=\"/sales-invoices?Customer=39cb2507-d07f-4357-987f-4451feee7b23&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\">3</a></span></td><td class=\"content observer:blur-sm observer:hover:blur-none observer:hover:transition text-right w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\"><a href=\"/customer-transactions?Customer=39cb2507-d07f-4357-987f-4451feee7b23&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\">$ 130.00</a></span></td></tr><tr><td style=\"width: 1px\"><a href=\"/customer-form?Key=787cf96e-3267-453c-868f-03f4ad452a3e&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\" class=\"bg-white border border-neutral-300 text-neutral-700 rounded py-1 px-4 hover:border-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-neutral-100 hover:shadow-inner dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700\" style=\"font-size: 11px\">Edit</a></td><td style=\"width: 1px\"><a href=\"/customer-view?Key=787cf96e-3267-453c-868f-03f4ad452a3e&amp;Position=2&amp;MaxPosition=3&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\" class=\"bg-white border border-neutral-300 text-neutral-700 rounded py-1 px-4 hover:border-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-neutral-100 hover:shadow-inner dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700\" style=\"font-size: 11px\">View</a></td><td class=\"content text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span>D002</span></td><td class=\"content \"><span>customer 2</span></td><td class=\"content \"><span>B2</span></td><td class=\"content text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\"><a href=\"/sales-invoices?Customer=787cf96e-3267-453c-868f-03f4ad452a3e&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\">1</a></span></td><td class=\"content observer:blur-sm observer:hover:blur-none observer:hover:transition text-right w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\"><a href=\"/customer-transactions?Customer=787cf96e-3267-453c-868f-03f4ad452a3e&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\">$ 223.75</a></span></td></tr><tr><td style=\"width: 1px\"><a href=\"/customer-form?Key=cdb7ee28-3c2a-4b50-b421-3c42a7bbcd02&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\" class=\"bg-white border border-neutral-300 text-neutral-700 rounded py-1 px-4 hover:border-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-neutral-100 hover:shadow-inner dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700\" style=\"font-size: 11px\">Edit</a></td><td style=\"width: 1px\"><a href=\"/customer-view?Key=cdb7ee28-3c2a-4b50-b421-3c42a7bbcd02&amp;Position=3&amp;MaxPosition=3&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\" class=\"bg-white border border-neutral-300 text-neutral-700 rounded py-1 px-4 hover:border-neutral-400 hover:text-neutral-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-neutral-100 hover:shadow-inner dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700\" style=\"font-size: 11px\">View</a></td><td class=\"content text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span>D003</span></td><td class=\"content \"><span>customer 3</span></td><td class=\"content \"><span>B1</span></td><td class=\"content text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\"><a href=\"/sales-invoices?Customer=cdb7ee28-3c2a-4b50-b421-3c42a7bbcd02&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\">-</a></span></td><td class=\"content observer:blur-sm observer:hover:blur-none observer:hover:transition text-right w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold\"><a href=\"/customer-transactions?Customer=cdb7ee28-3c2a-4b50-b421-3c42a7bbcd02&amp;FileID=VGVzdA&amp;Referrer=L2N1c3RvbWVycz9Ta2lwPTAmVGFrZT01MCZGaWxlSUQ9VkdWemRB\">- $ 60.00</a></span></td></tr><tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th class=\"observer:blur-sm observer:hover:blur-none observer:hover:transition font-semibold text-neutral-500 text-shadow text-center w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><div>4</div></th><th class=\"observer:blur-sm observer:hover:blur-none observer:hover:transition font-semibold text-neutral-500 text-shadow text-right w-px whitespace-nowrap\"><div>$ 293.75</div></th></tr></tbody>"}
```

This is my attempt:

```
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:55667/customers?FileID=VGVzdA'

var x = document.querySelector("#printable-content > table:nth-child(1) > thead > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > b:nth-child(1)").textContent;

fetch(url).then(function (response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function (html) {

// Convert the HTML string into a document object
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var y = doc.querySelector("#table > div.overflow-x-auto.lg\\:overflow-visible.no-scrollbar > table").innerHTML;

// Getting data from spans
    myObj = {innerHTML:"yyy"};
    myObj.innerHTML = y;
    items = JSON.stringify(myObj);
    console.log(items);


}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    alert('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```

and this is desired result which is all the span elements in the html:

```
{
"data": [
"D001",
"customer 1",
"A1",
"4",
"$ 155.00",
"D002",
"customer 2",
"B2",
"1",
"$ 223.75",
"D003",
"customer 3",
"B1",
"-",
"- $ 60.00"
]
}
```

Comment: `table > div.overflow-x-auto.lg\\:overflow-visible` <-- I've never seen `\\:` in a selector before - is that intentional? What does it do?

Comment: I have no idea, to be honest. I got this when I clicked `Copy Selector` on the table. The HTML is from an accounting software called Manager.io its free you can check it out if you want (I have no affiliation with them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this so I'm gonna post my answer here for others:

```
// Convert the HTML string into a document object
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    var y = doc.querySelector("#table > div.overflow-x-auto.lg\\:overflow-visible.no-scrollbar > table");
    
// Getting data from spans
    var appendText = [];
    const nodeList = y.querySelectorAll("span");
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
      appendText.push(nodeList[i].textContent);
    }
    var itemsObj = {data:appendText};
    data = JSON.stringify(itemsObj);
    console.log(data);
```